# auto insert records into table comment in K2 module in Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla-k2

In K2 I see a lot of spam comments with links, etc in it. 
I would like to know if there's a wait to not get these annoying spam messages.
I tried enabling the option tonot automatically publish comments but that gives me heaps of work every day to delete all the spam and to look what is not spam!
Autopublishing the comments does gives me crappy comments every day!

Isn't there a recaptcha fucntion to enable on the K2 Comments or another extension that works with K2 and is better for comments?

Comment: This question is about Joomla extensions, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem
go to extension-K2 choose parameters and then go the Comment Tab
then go down to recaptcha and choose enable captcha.